# Unable to Split Routes into Separate Files in Express 4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect all my routes ending with `/api` to a `manager.js` which will then route it to `/me`.

So, a fully qualified request to `/me` should look like `/api/me`. Splitting routes up into separate files was easy in Express 3.x, but I'm having trouble in 4.0.

**app.js**

```
app.use('/api',require('./routes/manager'));
```

**manager.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var manager = express.Router();
module.exports = function() {    
    manager.use('/me',require('../routes/me'));
};
```

**me.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var me = express.Router();

module.exports = function() {

    me.route('/')
        .get(function(req,res){
            res.send("Welcome to Me");
    });

};
```

When I go to `localhost:8080/api/me`, nothing happens, the page keeps loading.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't it still be `manager.use('/api/me', ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not quite properly passing through the `Router` objects. Keep in mind that this is what you are trying to do:

```
app.use('/api', express.Router());
```

but what you are effectively doing right now is this:

```
app.use('/api', function(){
    express.Router()
});
```

So you instead of exporting a function, you should be exporting the `Router` itself.

**manager.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var manager = express.Router();

manager.use('/me',require('../routes/me'));

module.exports = manager;
```

**me.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var me = express.Router();

me.route('/').get(function(req,res){
    res.send("Welcome to Me");
});

module.exports = me;
```