# Breaking out express routes into separate files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried every answer I've found on s/o, and I'm sure I must be missing something. What doesn't error on me instead gives me a 404. I tried answers from [Organize routes in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602212/organize-routes-in-node-js?lq=1),  strongloop's [route-separation](https://github.com/strongloop/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation) pattern, the answers from [How to include route handlers in multiple files in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059246/how-to-include-route-handlers-in-multiple-files-in-express), hit similar errors as in [Router.use requires middleware function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809485/router-use-requires-middleware-function) but none of those answers worked, either. The answer for [Unable to Split Routes into Separate Files in Express 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396592/unable-to-split-routes-into-separate-files-in-express-4-0) doesn't error, but also 404s. It seems like each answer has a different syntax and style, and maybe it's that I'm mixing and matching incorrectly?

Right now my /routes/persons.js has this pattern:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var persons = express.Router();

    persons.route('/persons/:user_id')
        .put(function (req, res, next) {
            // etc
    });

    module.exports = persons;
```

In my server.js file, I've got:

```
    var persons = require('./routes/persons');
    app.use('/persons', persons);
```

This combination doesn't throw errors, but it also doesn't do anything. I've tried adding the endpoint to server.js lines:

```
    var persons = require('./routes/persons');
    app.get('/persons/:user_id', persons.addpersons);
```

and stripping persons.js down to just export functions:

```
    exports.addpersons = function (req, res, next) {
            var list = req.body;
            // etc
    }
```

Plus variations like wrapping the whole person.js file in `module.exports = function()`, sticking `module.exports = router` at the end, using `app` instead of `router`, etc.

What am I overlooking? Should I be adding some other middleware, rearranging how I call the endpoint, using app, or sticking with router.route? What are the most likely culprits when there's no error but the endpoint is still 404'ing?

many thanks in advance!

============= EDITED TO INCLUDE SERVER.JS =============

Since it's clear something is set wrong, somewhere, here's my server.js file:

```
        var express = require('express');
        var app = express();
        var methodOverride = require('method-override');
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        var router = express.Router();
        var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken');
        var config = require('./config');
        var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
        var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
        var crypto = require('crypto');
        var async = require('async');

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'email@gmail.com',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });

        // I don't know if both are necessary, used multiple conflicting tutorials
        app.use(require('express-session')({
            secret: 'secret',
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false
        }));
        app.set('superSecret', config.secret);

        var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
            Person = require('./models/person.js'),
            User = require('./models/user.js'),
            Event = require('./models/event.js');

        var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
        mongoose.connect(config.database);

        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

        // routes go here

        app.use('/api', router);
        app.listen(port);
        console.log('gogogo port ' + port);
```

I have no idea where else I might look for why including routes requires such a break in the usual pattern. My config files? My procfile? Those are the only other files sitting on the server, not counting /models and /routes.

Comment: try `app.use('/persons/*', persons);`

Comment: No error, but still 404'd. :(

Comment: I see below that you had typo error, that solved the problem? else i will look into it and figure it out.

Comment: Nope, the typo was from me editing once I copied over, and not the issue in the original. I wish it were that easy! When I add the router.use 'something is happening' part from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923365/how-to-separate-routes-on-node-js-and-express-4 question, that does work! It still won't read the rest, but that at least tells me the file's getting loaded, I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is to understand what `app.use()` does to your `req` object (in particular to `req.path`), how `app.get()` and friends are different, and how Express wraps [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) (its internal path matching module) to handle routes.

1) `app.use(path, middleware)` **mounts** the middleware. Inside the mounted middleware/router, `req.path` is relative to the mount path. Only the beginning of the request path needs to match, so `/foo` will work for requests at `/foo` (relative path will be `/`), `/foo/bar` (relative path is `/bar`), etc.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Main: %s %s', req.method, req.path);
    next();
});

app.use('/foo', function (req, res) {
    console.log('In /foo: %s %s', req.method, req.path);
    res.send('Got there');
});
```

Try running the setup above, navigate to `localhost/foo` and see the following logs:

```
Main: GET /foo
In /foo: GET /
```

2) `app.get(path, middleware)`, `app.post(path, middleware)` etc. do **not mount** the target middlewares, so `req.path` is preserved. `req.path` must match the whole pattern you defined your route with, so `/foo` will only work for `/foo` requests.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Main: %s %s', req.method, req.path);
    next();
});

app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
    console.log('In /foo: %s %s', req.method, req.path);
    res.send('Got there');
});
```

Navigate to `localhost/foo` and see :

```
Main: GET /foo
In /foo: GET /foo
```

3) `app.route(path)`, as explained in the Express docs, is just a convenience to define multiple `app.get(middleware)`, `app.post(middleware)` etc. sharing the same `path`.

---

Now in your case, here is a working setup:

**main**

```
var persons = require('./routes/persons');
app.use('/persons', persons);
```

**routes/persons.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.route('/:user_id')
  .post(function (req, res) {
    // handle potato data
  })
  .get(function (req, res) {
    // get and send potato data
  });

module.exports = router;
```

This is convenient as you only have to set the `/persons` entry point once in your main file, so you can easily update it later on if needed (you could also import that path value from a config file, from your router object or whatever, Node is pretty flexible in this regard). The *persons* router itself takes care of its business controllers, regardless of where it is exactly mounted at.

Comment: I had to re-add mongoose so it'd recognize the schema for Persons, but the rest I kept like your example. I don't get any errors in the server console, but the browser says it's a 404, and the page is blank. I really do appreciate the explanation, but I have no idea why it won't work, or any idea of possible culprits (a conflict somewhere? a dependency? I don't know). Thanks, though!

Comment: Just tried this setup in a dummy projet and it works fine for me. I assume you have your middlewares send some data ? If this persists then try `console.log` in some parts of your app / middlewares to see where your request is routed to.

Comment: I have no doubt your version works, I just don't know why I can't get it to work. I do have my server.js console.logged within an inch of its life, which is how I knew that doing app.get in server.js and router.use in the /routes file worked, but I got errors if I tried to then hit route.anything-else. That's why I suspect it must be conflict, or a quirk introduced by something earlier in server.js. Will edit question to include that, so you can see.

Answer (score 1):

I FIGURED IT OUT!

Of course, this might be the totally wrong way to go about it (pls tell me if so) but it WORKS.

in my server.js file, I have:

```
    var persons = require('./routes/persons');
    router.get('/persons/:user_id', persons);
    router.post('/persons/:user_id', persons);
```

and my persons.js file now looks like this:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        Person = require('../models/person.js');

    router.post('/persons/:user_id', function (req, res) {
        var potatoBag = req.body;
        Person.collection.insert(potatoBag, function onInsert(err, potatoBag) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.status(200).end();
            }
        });
    });

    router.get('/persons/:user_id', function(req, res) {
        var id = req.params.user_id;
        Person.find({'user_id':id},function(err, person) {
            if (err)
                return res.json(err);
            res.send(person);
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

This seems like more overhead than most of the examples, but maybe it's because of a) using router.route and b) using imported schemas? I also had `(req, res, next)` in there, and it threw fits until I removed the `next` pieces. Probably still a bit awkward, but hey, it's working. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
persons.route('/persons/:user_id')
    .put(function (req, res, next) {
        // etc
});
```

do:

```
persons.put('/persons/:user_id',function (req, res, next) {
  // etc
});
```

Comment: I'd tried it both ways, actually, since I saw both patterns in the various other answers. What seemed to do the trick was changing `app.get` in server.js to `router.get` and then it suddenly all worked. I don't know why, since I didn't see that pattern in any answer, but it works, so... :)